# kruskal.test shows "All group levels must be finite" error. What is the problem?

Tags: r

I have a data set having a value and a group, e.g.,

```
Val Grp
123 "A"
231 "A"
132 "A"
234 "A"
445 "B"
345 "B"
235 "B"
345 "B"
```

(The original dataset would be too large to show here.)

When I now do `kruskal.test(data$Val, data$Grp)`, I get an error saying `all group levels must be finite.` When I check the data with `is.finite()`, I can see that all values are indeed finite.

The internet does not yield a lot of information on this error, so I have hope that someone could shed light on what this error means and what the problem could be.

Comment: what happens when you type `table(data$Grp)`?

Comment: Looking at the code, you'd get the message because it hits this line:  `if (!all(is.finite(g)))`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It should work if you run

```
data$Grp <- as.factor(data$Grp)
```

Then (as before):

```
kruskal.test(data$Val, data$Grp)
```

This is because `Grp` is a character not a factor and `is.finite` applied to an object of character class is always false (see `?is.finite`).

Comment: That was indeed it. Thanks a lot, I would never have gotten this idea!

Comment: Same issue, same solution with `fligner.test()`.
Nice catch @orizon!

Comment: Or without changing the data frame: `kruskal.test(data$Val, as.factor(data$Grp))`